# Single line textbox template in WPF with flat border

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a textbox template in WPF, which has a single line of text and a flat (non-3d) border. If the text is too large for the field, it should scroll horizontally without showing  scroll bar (like an address or search bar in a browser.) However with my code, when the text is wider than the textbox, it stills goes to a new line. My xaml is as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="SingleLineTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="White">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Your style working fine here.have you assigned textwrapping property to textbox <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBox> ? try by setting TextWrapping="NoWrap"

Comment: Yup, that was it! New to WPF so totally missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try by setting **TextWrapping="NoWrap"**